# How to create an annex when I have changed the structure of \chapter{}?

Tags: sectioning

How to create an annex when I have changed the structure of `\chapter{}` ? I've also changed the structure of `\chapter*{}` with a similar code.

Here the full code of the change:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@
{\reset@font
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\LARGE Chapitre \thechapter\par\nobreak}%
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{30\p@}
\interlinepenalty\@M
\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
{\raggedright \Huge #1}%
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
\hrule height 1pt
\par\nobreak
\vskip 45\p@
}}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: And what do you want this annex to look like? Are you planning to introduce it using `\chapter`? Please describe in detail the desired resulting output.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, the same strcture but with "Annex A", "Annex B" instead of "Chapter A"..

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, it would be better to introduce it using `\chapter` by preserving the structure of chapters, but, you can define another environment if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option using `\appendix` so the numbering changes to alphabetic; I also changed the hardcoded "Chapitre" in the redefinition to `\@chapapp` so the string changes in appendices from `\chaptername` to `\appendixname`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand\chaptername{Chapitre}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Annex}

\makeatletter
\let\@oldmakechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@
{\reset@font
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\LARGE\@chapapp~\thechapter\par\nobreak}%
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{30\p@}
\interlinepenalty\@M
\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
{\raggedright \Huge #1}%
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
\hrule height 1pt
\par\nobreak
\vskip 45\p@
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A modified chapter heading}

\appendix
\chapter{An anex with modified chapter heading}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The annex:

[image]

If `babel` is loaded with the appropriate module, the names will localize automatically; for example, using

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

the lines

```
\renewcommand\chaptername{Chapitre}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Annex}
```

are not required, and `\chaptername` will be "Chapitre" and `\appendixname`, "Annexe".